# Can't convert double to Double in Eclipse 4.3.1 Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse

I just installed the Eclipse Kepler SR2 package with 'Java 8 support for Eclipse Kepler SR2'. Compiler compliance level is set at 1.8. Installed jre is jre1.8.0_25. 
Java 8 is installed on my laptop.
I kept having this 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to Double' error using Eclipse.
It seems like the compiler cannot convert between them automatically.

But when I tried the same code in DrJava, everything worked fine. DrJava Version : drjava-20140826-r5761; DrJava Build Time: 20140826-0459

I also tried to run the java file in cmd and it worked fine as well. Weird or What!!!???
Why? Below is the code:

```
    
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class TempConvGUI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fahrString;
        Double fahr, cel;

        fahrString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the temperature in F");
        fahr = new Double(fahrString);
        cel = (fahr - 32) * 5.0/9.0;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The temperature in C is, " + cel);
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: show the problematic code.

Comment: Which compiler version are you using?  As you describe, any other IDE/compiler works fine.

Comment: Check the currently used Java Version, because your compiler may use a lower version than installed. You need at least Java 5, which included the autoboxing feature.

Comment: Check the Compiler compliance level in the Preferences > Java > Java Compiler (also in project properties). It needs to be at least 1.5

Comment: The Compiler compliance level under JDK Compliance is 1.4 at the moment. But should I change it to 1.5, 1.6 or 1.7?

Comment: Is it because this package does not support java 8? I have jdk1.8.0_25 installed but in eclipse I cannot find it....

Comment: Try a newer version of eclipse such as Luna. I just made a quick check in my eclipse (Luna). The compiler compliance level is 1.7 and your code works fine in my eclipse.

Comment: @SimonWoo I just installed the latest Luna, and it worked fine.